# How to install custom c library?

Tags: c, libraries

I just wanted to add a c library to Ubuntu which was created by Harvard University for cs50 course. They provided instructions for how to install the library which is listed below.

---

Debian, Ubuntu

First become root, as with:

```
sudo su -
```

Then install the CS50 Library as follows:

```
apt-get install gcc
wget http://mirror.cs50.net/library/c/cs50-library-c-3.1.zip
unzip cs50-library-c-3.1.zip
rm -f cs50-library-c-3.1.zip
cd cs50-library-c-3.1
gcc -c -ggdb -std=c99 cs50.c -o cs50.o
ar rcs libcs50.a cs50.o
chmod 0644 cs50.h libcs50.a
mkdir -p /usr/local/include
chmod 0755 /usr/local/include
mv -f cs50.h /usr/local/include
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
chmod 0755 /usr/local/lib
mv -f libcs50.a /usr/local/lib
cd ..
rm -rf cs50-library-c-3.1
```

---

I did exactly as directed. But the compiler reported “Undefined reference to a function”--the function was Get String. So, I searched for a solution and found one. It said to use the `-l` switch.

Now when I compile I use something like:

gcc –o hello.c hello –lcs50

(I don’t remember the exact command.)

However, I cannot use the `make` command, which is easier to use.

I understand that there is some problem with linking the library. What is a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Please reproduce the error and **provide all the output of the command that produces the errors** (including non-error output, if any) by **editing your question**. While editing your question, paste it in, select it, and use the `<$>` tool in the Ask Ubuntu editing toolbar to make it appear correctly.

Comment: The correct comman is: gcc –o hello hello.c –lcs50 You accidentally remove your hello.c using your compiled hello

Answer (score 2):

I am taking CS50 as well, and I have the same problem.
After following Cs50's instructions, I get this error when compiling code using gc

```
/tmp/ccvUiSKS.o: In function `main':
Goodmario.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `GetInt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have followed the instructions to the exact.
I believe that you should just continue using -lcs50, it's not any harder.
eg. The command I use to compile a program

```
gcc Goodmario.c -o Goodmario -std=c99 -lcs50
```

Not very hard : D

Answer (score 2):

you should add the following command to make GetInt work:

$ gcc hello.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lcs50 -o hello

rename "hello.c# and "hello" with your input file and your desired output name.
The option -I/usr/local/include tells gcc to also look in /usr/local/include for header files. The option -L/usr/local/lib tells gcc (in the linking phase) to also look for libraries in /usr/local/lib, and the option -lcs50 tells gcc which libraries you need.

source: ubuntuforum.org